# Release upgrade for Ubuntu EC2 AMI launches SSH on a different port

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, ssh, amazon-ec2

sudo do-release-upgrade on a Ububtu EC2 AMI shows the following warning message, is it safe to continue or what would be the preferred procedure.

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Continue running under SSH? 

This session appears to be running under ssh. It is not recommended 
to perform a upgrade over ssh currently because in case of failure it 
is harder to recover. 

If you continue, an additional ssh daemon will be started at port 
'1022'. 
Do you want to continue? 

Continue [yN] N
```

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to continue, this is opening a second SSH daemon on port 1022 in case SSH fails/crashes during the upgrade you have the ability to ssh in to port 1022 if need be to repair. (The likelihood of something failing w/ssh is very very low)